# How to get post title by javascript before submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, post

[image]

I'm trying to get the Post Title of wordpress post before it is submitted for Publish or Pending for Review etc. I'm using the codes shown in the image. Please see the image.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#publish').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var title = $('#title').val();
      /** do whatever with the title here */
      });
 });
```